# raising an event inside a user control that returns CommandEventArgs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, commandargument

hi all i have the following problam:

i have a user control which i want to raise an event from to the page that is using that user control (its a button)

anyway my problem started when i wanted to put this user control inside a repeater instead of another button (regular asp:button) 
anyway i needed to support CommandArgument so that page can use the button

so i created a property:

```
    Private m_CommandArgument As Object
Public Property CommandArgument() As Object
    Get
        Return m_CommandArgument
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As Object)
        m_CommandArgument = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

but... when i try to raise the event this property dosnt keep his state...

```
cmdEvent = New CommandEventArgs(CommandName, CommandArgument)
```

so after i press the button and the postback happen my raised event dosnt have a value..
where should this property be saved in order for it to have a value after postback?
view state? how do i add to the the viewstate automaticly?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i figured out a way i can do this...

and its very simple like so:

```
Private m_CommandArgument As Object
Public Property CommandArgument() As Object
    Get
        'Return m_CommandArgument
        Return ViewState("confirmCommandArgument")
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As Object)
        ViewState("confirmCommandArgument") = Value
        'm_CommandArgument = 
    End Set
End Property
```

so actualy simply saving it in the viewstate...